# Getting NSTableView row index of focussed row?

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa, nstableview

How can I obtain the index of the row in a `NSTableView` that is currently being focussed? When left-clicked the row is selected but I need the index when the row is right-clicked on, i.e. the row might not be selected when the user opens a context menu upon it but the row does receive focus. I can't find any details in the docs on how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain the right-clicked row's index from `tableView.clickedRow`. Note that if user right-clicked on a selected (highlighted) row, the system will "focus" *all* selected rows (provided that there are multiple selected rows; you can try it in Finder). So you may want to take that into consideration, too.

Possible implementation:

```
int clickedRow = tableView.clickedRow;
NSIndexSet *focusedIndexes;
if (clickedRow != -1) {
    if ([tableView isRowSelected:clickedRow]) {
        focusedIndexes = tableView.selectedRowIndexes;
    } else {
        focusedIndexes = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:clickedRow];
    }
    // do what you desire with focusedIndexes
}
```